# Where did Keats write “wrinkled brow and sneer of cold command”?

Tags: quote-source, john-keats

[Face to Face with Hon. Henry Litton GBM CBM JP, Former Permanent Judge of the Court of Final Appeal | Hong Kong Lawyer](http://www.hk-lawyer.org/content/face-face-hon-henry-litton-gbm-cbm-jp-former-permanent-judge-court-final-appeal)

> A good judge is also humble – they “see the world as the common man and woman sees it.” They don’t judge from “some great height”, with a *“wrinkled brow and sneer of cold command”*, he said, referencing the poet Keats.

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=keats++%E2%80%9Cwrinkled+brow+and+sneer+of+cold+command%E2%80%9D) couldn't find it.

[image: Image of results Google search for "keats wrinkled brow and sneer of cold command", showing the response "It looks like there aren't great matches for your search" and a number of irrelevant responses.]

Comment: Keats didn't write that, Shelley did. "My name is Ozymandias, King of Kings, Look on my works, ye mighty, and despair . . ."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because it is a slight misquote, the line being

> And wrinkled lip, and sneer of cold command,

It's from [Ozymandias](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/46565/ozymandias), by Percy Shelley, not Keats.

Comment: That wouldn't help, either!